# Send data to Notification each X second?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there a way to first create a `Notification` and set some default `message` (the line below the title of a notification) and then to **change that message every X seconds**?

I tried finding solution, but those I found proposed constant killing and creating `Notification` which I do not find a proper way to achieve what I need.

I need to implement a small counter inside the same notification which will be updated every X seconds.

PS. Please do not confuse this with sending data **from** notification to an Activity. I need the reverse process - send data **from activity to** the notification.

Comment: Sorry for wrong title. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at android documentation

> Updating notifications
>
> To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a
>   notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(ID,
>   notification). To update this notification once you've issued it,
>   update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a
>   Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same
>   ID you used previously. If the previous notification is still visible,
>   the system updates it from the contents of the Notification object. If
>   the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is
>   created instead.
>
> The following snippet demonstrates a notification that is updated to
>   reflect the number of events that have occurred. It stacks the
>   notification, showing a summary:

Probably setting a notification id and accessing the same notification by id is the solution to your problem. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) is the link to document.

**Edit:**

Probably I missed one aspect of your question - i.e. creating new instance of notification. To resolve it you can declare an instance of notification in a singleton class. This way, you will not have to create an instance of notification again and again. Just modify the content of notification and use the same instance again and again.

Comment: This is the right way to do it: post a replacement notification with the same ID and tag and you should be all set. (Also make sure not to update the "when" so it doesn't move around in the list each time you update it.)